# Code reuse problem with a template Vector class for 3D math

Tags: c++, templates, 3d

I have a template  Vector class for 3D vector math. I'd like to have variants of this class of different type and size (e.g. Vec2i, Vec2f, Vec3i, Vec3f) and be able to construct one from the other, like so:

```
Vec2i v(1, 2);
Vec3f u = Vec3f(v, 0);
```

Currently, I have a number of constructors in Vector for accomplishing this. However, it seems incorrect to allow a Vec4 to be constructed in the same way as above:

```
Vec4f t = Vec3f(v, 0)
```

I'd like to have separate classes for Vec2*, Vec3*, Vec4* variants, but that means code duplication. How should I do this? Inheritance from a base Vector class? Implement each variant in terms of the original Vector class (i.e. the Vector class is a private member of each variant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Vec2 and a Vec3 are quite different IMO, what code reuse would you expect if they were related?

For the different built-in types, simply use template classes and template constructors:

```
template<typename T1> 
struct Vec2 {
    Vec2(T1 const & X, T1 const & Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}
    template <typename T2> 
    Vec2(Vec2<T2> const & V) {
        x = static_cast<T1>(V.x);
        y = static_cast<T1>(V.y);
    }

    T1 x, y;
};


template<typename T1> 
struct Vec3 {
    Vec3(T1 const & X, T1 const & Y, T1 const & Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {}
    template <typename T2> 
    Vec3(Vec3<T2> const & V) {
        x = static_cast<T1>(V.x); 
        y = static_cast<T1>(V.y);
        z = static_cast<T1>(V.z);
    }
    template <typename T2, typename T3> 
    Vec3(Vec2<T2> const & V, T3 const & Z) {
        x = static_cast<T1>(V.x);
        y = static_cast<T1>(V.y);
        z = static_cast<T1>(Z);
    }

    T1 x, y, z;
};
```

If you want to make Vec2 and Vec3 related, have the Vec3 template inherit the Vec2 template, then hide the functions you need to rewrite for Vec3.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this; I created a base Vector class that Vec2, Vec3, Vec4, Point2, and Point3 implement-in-terms-of in order to reuse Vector functionality but only expose a subset of its operations (as in the case of Point2 and Point3) or add functionality (the specialized constructors).

Answer (score 1):

Use templates. This is totally untested.

```
template <int N>
struct Vec
{
    Vec(const Vec<N - 1>& smaller_vec, double v) { std::copy(&smaller_vec.values[0], &smaller_vec.values[0] + N-1, &values[0]); values[N-1] = v; }

    double values[N];
};

template <>
struct Vec<1>
{
    Vec(double v) { values[0] = v; }

    double values[1];
};

Vec<3> v3(Vec<2>(Vec<1>(5), 6), 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
template <int size, typename T>
struct Vec
{
    Vec<size, T>() {}
    Vec<size, T>(Vec<size-1, T>, T val) {} // here's the fun
};

typedef Vec<2, float> Vec2f;
typedef Vec<3, float> Vec3f;
typedef Vec<4, float> Vec4f;
// ...

int main()
{
    Vec2f john;
    Vec3f casey(john, 0);
    Vec4f chuck(casey, 0);

    return 0;
}
```